# How to load custom files in Express automatically?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to load `index.html` when I request `http://localhost:4935/` so my code for this is like

```
const MODULES_DIR = '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/';
const APP_PORT = 4935;

var express = require(MODULES_DIR + 'express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require(MODULES_DIR + 'socket.io').listen(server),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

server.listen(APP_PORT);

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    if (fs.existsSync(__dirname + req.route.params))
        res.sendfile(__dirname + req.route.params);

    if (req.route.params == '/')
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

On this i get error:

```
web@web-X501A1 ~ $ node '/home/web/www/nodechat/server.js' 
   info  - socket.io started

http.js:691
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:691:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:63:22)
    at SendStream.type (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:456:7)
    at SendStream.send (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:348:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:323:10
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

As i understand from error the problem is that `res.sendfile` can be sent only once... Basically i need to automatically load all `JS` and `CSS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  ...
});
```

Use this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```